# Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.isClient()'

Tags: grails, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to use the spring-security-oauth2-provider-2.0-RC2 Grails plugin to make our application an oauth server, and I'm running into a number of issues. The most pressing is this: when attempting to access a protected resource annotated with `@Secured(["#oauth2.isClient()"])`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error 500: 
Servlet: default
URI: /api/user/info
Exception Message: EL1011E:(pos 8): Method call: Attempted to call method isClient() on null context object 
Caused by: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.isClient()'.
```

I have verified that I'm using the correct versions of both spring security core & cache. I have also tried disabling the cache plugin, to no avail. Stack trace is below: any ideas?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.isClient()'
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:13)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:51)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:35)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.checkOtherVoters(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:92)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.decide(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:44)

at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)

at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)

at com.kpi.dp.core.user.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.groovy:111)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)

at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)

at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)

at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)

at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)

at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:(pos 8): Method call: Attempted to call method isClient() on null context object

```
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:135)

at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:68)

at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:63)

at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)

at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)

at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)

at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)

... 62 more
```

Comment: Hi @Shawn, did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Hi, any solution? Have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the expression `authentication.isClientOnly()` instead.
Spring security makes `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` available as `authentication` for the expressions. 
`getAuthentication()` returns an `OAuth2Authentication` object, which has an `isClientOnly()` utility method.